# Javascript window.open size not working properly. Height okay, width messed up

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, size, window.open

I'm having trouble with some JavaScript and the window.open method.

I'm trying to control the size of the pop up depending on the current time. The hours control the height, and the minutes (rounded to the nearest five) control the width.

The height control is working fine, and corresponds to the correct values... However the width is always at 100% of my screen and I can't work out why.

I have put a test alert to show me the text it should be putting into the window.open method and this looks fine - in fact if I copy and paste the text from the alert into the code and re-load the page, then the height and width both work perfectly. Seems very odd.

Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 10.1" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var d = new Date();
var h = 10*(d.getHours())+300
var m = d.getMinutes();

m = 10*(Math.round(parseInt(m)/5)*5)+300;

var a = "width=";
var b = ", height=";

var size = "'"+a+m+b+h+"'";

var openWin = function(){window.open('','',size)};


function test() {alert(h); alert(m); alert(size);}

</script>
</head>


<body onload="test()">


<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are making a window who's size is hours and minutes?

Comment: The line `var size = "'"+a+m+b+h+"'";` is really making it hard to read (in general). I wouldn't recommend writing stuff like that

Comment: You can't reliably control window size, depending on doing so will certainly fail in at least some browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have quotes around the size.

What you want:

```
var size = a+m+b+h;
window.open('','',size)
```

OR

```
window.open('','', 'width=' + m + ', height=' + h)
```

What you currently have (after substituting size for what it really is):

```
window.open('','','"width=' + m + ', height=' + h +'"')
```

Which evaluates to:

```
window.open('','','"width=500, height=450"')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code.

1. you don't need parseInt(m). m already *is* type number. But if you still want to user parseInt here, specify a radix! Otherwise parseInt will guess, and this makes ever number withe leading zero be parsed als octal number rather than decimal.
2. Don't use "'" here: `"'"+a+m+b+h+"'";`. This won't make your string "more" string, it will just make ' part of your String. If you want to force type String when adding some variables, then just add an empty string first: `var myString = '' + a + b + c`.

This one will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... This fixed it, and I understand why, so I've learned something!

I didn't actually write the parseInt(m) bit - I got that from google, so I'm not really sure what it means! It would be great if you could give me a short explanation if you don't mind?

Comment: It parses a string and trys to make it a number:
http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/unabhaengig.htm#parse_int (consider up voting my answer if you like it.)

Comment: @LeJared—If the argument to [parseInt](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.2) is Type number and base 10 is required, there are no issues with not providing a radix. Also, *parseInt* doesn't guess the radix, it determines a default based on rules in ECMA-262. As of ES5, if no radix is supplied, it's always set to 10 (a leading zero must not cause *parseInt* to treat the value as octal). Though providing a radix is still a vary good idea while pre–ES5 implementations are in use.

Comment: Yes, parseInt does not change the number if it already is a number. But current implementation in browsers will trigger octal mode if there is a leading zero. You may easily check by yourself. Just try parseInt('08'); it gives 0.